# Starting the main(String args[]) from other package

Tags: program-entry-point

I was looking for a possibility to start the Main fom another class which has his own main. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: so... which language?

Answer (score 3):

`main(String args[])` is just like any other function. Depending on how you've declared it, you can call it on an instance of the other class or as a static method.

Answer (score 1):

i am pretty sure you can just call it, in most languages main is a static method, so you would call it as any other method from your main

Comment: depending on your environment, you may have an issue with multiple mains, you may need to specify which one to start when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done, if you have two classes in a program:

```
class Class1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Class1");
   }
}

class Class2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] strArray = new String[2];  //created an array to pass as argument
     Class1.main(strArray);
   }
}
```